# How do I get the latest object name uploaded in s3 and push that data(json) to a different api (hit an api) using AWS Lambda?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, aws-media-convert

this code shows all the objects uploaded in the bucket testbucket-101 and no api is being called. Basically the output json of the s3 event should be posted to a different API.

```
import boto3
import os

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
    bucket=s3.Bucket('testbucket-101')
    for key in bucket.objects.all():
        print(key.key)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can [Configuring Amazon S3 event notifications](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/NotificationHowTo.html) and register your lambda as the destination.

Even you can parse and extract the object name and bucket. Eventually, download the object and invoke the API

You'll receive an event somewhat like this
[Tutorial: Using AWS Lambda with Amazon S3](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-s3-example.html)

```json
{
  "Records":[
    {
      "eventVersion":"2.0",
      "eventSource":"aws:s3",
      "awsRegion":"us-west-2",
      "eventTime":"1970-01-01T00:00:00.000Z",
      "eventName":"ObjectCreated:Put",
      "userIdentity":{
        "principalId":"AIDAJDPLRKLG7UEXAMPLE"
      },
      "requestParameters":{
        "sourceIPAddress":"127.0.0.1"
      },
      "responseElements":{
        "x-amz-request-id":"C3D13FE58DE4C810",
        "x-amz-id-2":"FMyUVURIY8/IgAtTv8xRjskZQpcIZ9KG4V5Wp6S7S/JRWeUWerMUE5JgHvANOjpD"
      },
      "s3":{
        "s3SchemaVersion":"1.0",
        "configurationId":"testConfigRule",
        "bucket":{
          "name":"sourcebucket",
          "ownerIdentity":{
            "principalId":"A3NL1KOZZKExample"
          },
          "arn":"arn:aws:s3:::sourcebucket"
        },
        "object":{
          "key":"HappyFace.jpg",
          "size":1024,
          "eTag":"d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e",
          "versionId":"096fKKXTRTtl3on89fVO.nfljtsv6qko"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

[Enabling and configuring event notifications for an S3 Bucket](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/user-guide/enable-event-notifications.html)